# Minimizing buffer error

Tags: vector-grid, vector-tiles

I got a vector layer, that I would like to buffer in Rectangles (resembling a Raster layer).

However, when I buffer the vector points, there always is an error in the buffer (see picture)

[image]

I am pretty sure that the error occurs because the points are not facing *"true north"*, and that I could minimize the error significantly if I could *"tilt"* the points in the right direction so that there are no gaps between the rectangle buffers.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: How are you defining "error"? It looks like the software did what you asked. If you're looking to eliminate gaps and overlap, then using a Thiessen polygon generator is probably closer to your goal.

Comment: Yes, it did what it is supposed to do. The "error" that I mean is, as you said, the gaps in between. I have also done some light reading on  rotated pool grid coordinate systems that seem to solve this issue. However, I have no experience with them before. 

I will take a look at the polygon generator, thanks for the suggestion.